# Set PropertyGrid default view to "category view"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

How can I set PropertyGrid's view to "Category View" programmatically or in design-time?
I just can do it in run-time by clicking a button on the PropertyGrid's toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`PropertySort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertysort(v=vs.110).aspx) property  of your property grid to `Categorized` or `CategorizedAlphabetical` at design-time or by code:

```
this.propertyGrid1.PropertySort = PropertySort.Categorized;
```

[image]